# How to make the background overflow (in :before) visible

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want a circle with dynamic content. I am using a background image (SVG) and scale it so it is alway behind the content. It almost works. The background gets scaled but the overflow is not visible. So the left and right overflow, or the top and bottom depending on the screen width, are not visible.

```
.icwrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: visible;
    display: flex;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}

.iccont {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 45vw;
    padding: 7.5vw;
    height: auto;
    color: #FFF;}

.iccont h1 {
   font-size: 1.5em;
   font-weight: 700;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   line-height: 1.5em;}

.iccont p {
   line-height: 1.5em;}

.icwrap:before {
   content: '';
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   overflow: visible;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   background-position: center;
   background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/SVG_Circle.svg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;}
```

See my code like described above:
https://jsfiddle.net/g471tLzf/

I like the behavior. Is there a solution to display the overflow?

Comment: Not unless you are starting with a **square element**. Since `.icwrap` isn't square I think you may have problems. A background image can't exceed the bounds of its element into overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rectangle that can be inscribed in a circle has a maximum area that is a square having radius/sqrt(2) width.

Check the video if interested in underlying maths.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNMK92GVTO8.

So you can't solve this problem in general unless your content fits in every case inside that box.